# Java and Python return different sums and trying to compare with C++

Tags: java, python, c++

Why does Java and Python give a different output for the sum from 1 to a million. I tried on smaller numbers, the code output identical results for up to a 100 (5050)

Python

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()

sum = 0
for i in range(1,1000000+1):
    #print(i)
    sum+=i
print(sum)

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Java

```
package sum_1_to_1000;

public class sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++){
            //System.out.println(i);
            sum+=i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(Math.pow(totalTime*10, -3));
    }

}
```

I tried to do it in C++, but I'm still learning that. How to get the below code running, and print out the running time? Is there a place to run C++ online?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <=2; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
    printf("The Sum is: ", sum);
}
```

Comment: have you though about integer limitation on each language ?

Comment: An `int` in Java is limited to 4 bytes, and it's signed so it can only go up to `2^31-1`. Python `int`s have a wider range. In C++ I believe it ... depends.

Comment: Your C++ code is not compiling because printf()  needs stdio.h and you haven't specified anything like "%d".

Comment: Moreover, since your code is in C++ you can use cout for output purpose

Comment: you could try to use long instead of int in the java example as khelwood says you will get overflow in the sum integer.

Comment: @ GAURANG VYAS how to use cout? 

@Mathias used long, got the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++){
            //System.out.println(i);
            sum+=i;
}
```

the really `sum=(1+1000000)*500000=500000500000`, it is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE (2^31-1)`

Comment: You should find `Integer.MAX_VALUE` equivalents for Python (and C++) to complete this answer.

Comment: How to print the real number then? What other type should I use instead of int?

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE in java equals 2147483647 , you can use long in java is 8 bytes length； in python2 , there is int and long , In Python 2, there's sys.maxint =9223372036854775807(2^63 - 1) ;  but in python3 , there is just only int ,  in Python 3 the int type is  the same as the long type in Python 2

Answer (score 0):

I have buddies that use repl.it 
https://repl.it/languages
has a lot of languages you can choose from to use. Just remember you are running this on someone else's servers so be careful with sensitive information

Answer (score -2):

Also i've used CodeChef.com in the past to compile code online.

Comment: @molbdnilo Nah, he just answer the last question asking for an external resource "_Is there a place to run C++ online?_" even if (s)he should not ;) (Well I guess this is what it is)

Comment: I tried codecheff, c++14 works, but not c++ 4.9.2. What is the difference? How to print the execution time? Is there another print command where I print the variable alone, without any formatting? Same as with Java, Int doesn't return the entire value, is there any type besides int that i can use?